# Why is git ignoring my SSH Key in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts?

Tags: git, github, ssh, puppet, ssh-keys

I have added the `github.com` SSH Key to `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`. But when I run

```
git clone git@github.com:me/repo
```

I still get

```
Cloning into 'repo'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

- If I add the key to `~/.ssh/known_hosts` it works as expected, no prompt.
- I am running this on a debian machine.
- I would like this to work directly using file `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` as there are several users.
- I also can't type `'yes'`, because this is running in `puppet`.
- For security reasons we can't use `StrictHostKeyChecking = no`.
- I have no `~/.ssh/config` file.
- (edit) I have also restarted `sshd` since modifying `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`.

How do I force git to use `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`?

Edit 1:

This is the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` (and `~/.ssh/config` doesn't exist):

```
# This is the ssh client system-wide configuration file.  See
# ssh_config(5) for more information.  This file provides defaults for
# users, and the values can be changed in per-user configuration files
# or on the command line.

# Configuration data is parsed as follows:
#  1. command line options
#  2. user-specific file
#  3. system-wide file
# Any configuration value is only changed the first time it is set.
# Thus, host-specific definitions should be at the beginning of the
# configuration file, and defaults at the end.

# Site-wide defaults for some commonly used options.  For a comprehensive
# list of available options, their meanings and defaults, please see the
# ssh_config(5) man page.

Host *
#   ForwardAgent no
#   ForwardX11 no
#   ForwardX11Trusted yes
#   RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#   RSAAuthentication yes
#   PasswordAuthentication yes
#   HostbasedAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIAuthentication no
#   GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#   GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#   GSSAPITrustDNS no
#   BatchMode no
#   CheckHostIP yes
#   AddressFamily any
#   ConnectTimeout 0
#   StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
#   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
#   Port 22
#   Protocol 2
#   Cipher 3des
#   Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#   MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#   EscapeChar ~
#   Tunnel no
#   TunnelDevice any:any
#   PermitLocalCommand no
#   VisualHostKey no
#   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
#   RekeyLimit 1G 1h
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

and this is my `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`:

```
# HEADER: This file was autogenerated at 2020-12-31 10:33:06 +0000
# HEADER: by puppet.  While it can still be managed manually, it
# HEADER: is definitely not recommended.
gerrit.wikimedia.org ssh-rsa AAAAB3Nz[...]
github ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzAAAAB3Nz[...]
```

Edit 2:

all have read permissions on `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ls -la /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 795 Dec 31 10:33 /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

Comment: This is not Git's doing. Don't look at Git. Look to ssh; it's ssh's fault. Is there a GlobalKnownHostsFile setting somewhere? See https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/

Comment: Thank you torek, I can't find any GlobalKnownHostsFile related setting in /etc/ssh/ssh_config and ~/.ssh/config doesn't exist. please see edit 1

Comment: Have you restarted `sshd` since you edited `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`?

Comment: Thank you William, I have just restarted with `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`, but unfortunately that does not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your known hosts file is incorrectly formatted.  The first entry in each line is the name of the system you're connecting to.  In this case, that needs to be `github.com`, not a plain `github`.  This is the technique that OpenSSH uses to find the appropriate key.

You can find the correct format by using `ssh-keyscan github.com`.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an SSH problem. The SSH(1) man page states:

> ssh automatically maintains and checks a database containing identification for all hosts it has ever been used with. Host keys are stored in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` in the user's home directory. Additionally, the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` is automatically checked for known hosts.

Your issue might be that the un-elevated user cannot read the `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` file.

There is a caveat to ssh where if you run something like `sudo ssh-keygen -R domain.com`, it can modify your existing `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts/` file to be only readable by root. (`-rw------- root root`). You might want to use `chown` or `chmod` to change permissions of this file to make sure it is readable without root privileges.

```sh
sudo chmod +r /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob, I can `cat` out the file with a non root user. I have also added edit 2 with the current permissions for the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts`, all users can read.